# How Secure is MMS Messaging

Tags: security, mms

I recieved a few MMS messages from a friend containging confidential documents as he didnt have internet access where he stayed for a project.

How secure is it? can anyone in the IT department of the celullar company of the recieving or sending person access the data from the server??

i have no idea how it works but all information would be appreciated/

Comment: The Indian government has made many efforts to ensure the tap-ability of mobile messaging, including forcing RIM to introduce a backdoor into their secure corporate email service so that the Indian government can intercept messages. They never issued a ban on BlackBerry MMS messaging because it's relatively easy for them to intercept those already. Nokia and Apple have also provided such facilities to the Indian government.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you define as an IT department.

The "internal" IT department who deal with computers will most likely have no access to your data.

That being said, it really depends on your network and their infrastructure, however, most likely, someone somewhere will have access - but is highly unlikely to ever use it.

Your MMS has to go over your providers network and will most likely be backed up and depending on your countries regulations, could easily be logged.

This being said, unless you are a suspect, being tapped or similar, the chances of you actually being targeted or someone looking at your data, it is highly unlikely anyone will ever look at your data.

e.g. I perform hosting and web mail for many clients... I use password protection, encryption and other technologies... but, I also backup all data and if I really tried, I could decrypt/view data - but, I never would... Sometimes it just comes down to trust with your provider.

Comment: thanks it helps a lot ....

we are based in India and the network in use is not even 2 years old and the technology is provided bt NTT DOcomo from japan so i guess its secure

Comment: That's not a very good guarantee. The chances of someone between you and Gmail's webservers looking in on the transferred email data is low too, but Gmail still uses SSL because otherwise it'd be trivial for someone in between to see the data. And [it's not just criminals who have to worry about wiretaps anymore](http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/91805). If the police are willing to send undercover officers to [spy on peace activists](https://www.google.com/search?q=police+undercover+peace+activist), then just about anyone could be the target of cheaper illegal surveillance.